# How to check if an extention is installed

Tags: ios, imessage-extension

We offer multiple iMessage extensions. Example ExtensionA and ExtensionB.

ExtensionB offers InApp purchases InAppPurchaseA and InAppPurchaseB.

InAppPurchaseA should be free, if ExtensionA is installed on the device.

How to check if ExtensionA is installed?

Comment: You can create common server API for both extension(A & B)  . Whenever the person install the extension then it will send the trigger to sever about installation along with unique ID.