# Can we programatically check if sticker pack is installed in iMessage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, ios10

I am new to sticker packs for iMessage and I searched through Apple documents but could not find answer.

For example, I have launched a sticker pack for iMessage app. If user has purchased that sticker pack, in my separate app, I want to award him some points if he has already purchased and installed a sticker pack. Is there a way I can programatically check if a particular user has purchased it in my separate app?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574375/how-to-check-if-an-extention-is-installed